# Why the vertical asymptote of y=f(x) is the zeros of $1/f(x)$?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, function-and-relation-composition, rational-functions, characteristic-functions

Why the vertical asymptote of $y=f(x)$ is the zeros of $1/f(x)$? For example, if $f(x)$ has a vertical asymptote $x=1$, then $(1,0)$ must be a x-intercept of $1/f(x)$?

I saw this in IB textbook and I want to know why.

> the vertical asymptotes of $y = f(x)$ become zeros of $y = \frac{1}{f(x)}$

Comment: Your statement is a little vague and possibly false.  Can you give a specific $f(x)$ that you're thinking about?

Comment: For $f(x) = \frac{z^2+2z+1}{z+1}$ this is not the case, as there are no vertical asymptotes.

Comment: Often $f(x)$ is undefined at $a$ if the line $x=a$ is a vertical asymptote, and then $1/f(x)$ is also undefined at $a$, so strictly speaking the claim doesn't make sense. (But one might get a removable singularity, of course.) And if $f(a)$ *is* defined, then definitely $1/f(a)$ can't be zero...

Comment: By the way, what is “IB textbook”?

Comment: @HansLundmark IB = [International Baccalaureate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Baccalaureate).  It's an international secondary school curriculum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're saying this:

> If the graph of $f(x)$ has a vertical asymptote at $x=a$, then $1/f(a)=0$.

**Example:** Let $f(x) = \frac{x+1}{x-1}$.  This has a vertical asymptote at $x=1$.  The reciprocal expression is $\frac{x-1}{x+1}$, and the associated function has a zero at $x=1$.

But this is being very sloppy about the relation between a function and its reciprocal.  The reciprocal of $f(x)=\frac{x+1}{x-1}$ is $\frac{1}{f(x)} = \frac{x-1}{x+1}$, *but* the domain of $f$ excludes $1$.  So actually
$$
    \frac{1}{f(x)} = \begin{cases} \frac{x-1}{x+1} & x \neq 1 \\
    \text{undefined} & x=1 \end{cases}
$$
So there is no value $a$ for which $\frac{1}{f(a)} = 0$.

And come to think of it, the equation $\frac{1}{f(a)} = 0$ is already problematic, because if it were satisfied, then
$$
    \frac{1}{f(a)} = 0 \implies 1 = 0 \cdot f(a) = 0.
$$
And this is a contradiction.

We can extend $f$ to give it a value at its asymptote, in such a way that the reciprocal is defined.  But that reciprocal value still won't be zero.  For instance, suppose we said
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{x+1}{x-1} & x \neq 1 \\
    2 & x=1 \end{cases}
$$
Then,
$$
\frac{1}{f(x)} = \begin{cases} \frac{x-1}{x+1} & x \neq 1 \\
    \frac{1}{2} & x=1 \end{cases}
$$
So $f$ has an asymptote at $x=1$, and $\frac{1}{f}$ is not zero at $x=1$.

---

I am wondering why this was written in your textbook when it's so wrong.  It could be that only a certain class of functions are being considered.  For instance, I think it's true for rational functions $f(x) = \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$, where $p$ and $q$ are polynomials.  This $f$ has vertical asymptotes when the denominator tends to zero and the numerator to something other than zero.  That is, if $q(a) = 0$ and $p(a) \neq 0$, then $f$ has a vertical asymptote at $a$.  Then the  reciprocal expression $f(x) = q(x)/p(x)$ does have a zero at $a$.  But this isn't quite the same thing as the function $\frac{1}{f(x)}$.